# Como pedir autenticação em um item do menu em Asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tenho o formulário de login que atualmente está sendo usado para entrar no sistema, mas preciso fazer essa autenticação também ao clicar em um determinado item do menu.
Preciso que ao clicar em "Home", peça essa autenticação novamente, e se o usuário tiver permissão entra, se não não entra.
Como faço isso ?

MasterPage:

```
<asp:Menu ID="Menu" runat="server" style="margin-bottom: 0" BackColor="White" 
            DynamicHorizontalOffset="2" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Overline="False" 
            Font-Size="Medium" Font-Strikeout="False" Font-Underline="False" 
            ForeColor="#7C6F57" StaticSubMenuIndent="10px" RenderingMode="List" OnMenuItemDataBound="NavigationMenu_MenuItemDataBound">
            <DynamicHoverStyle BackColor="#B2223D" ForeColor="White" />
            <DynamicMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="5px" ForeColor="White" />
            <DynamicMenuStyle BackColor="#5D7B9D"  ForeColor="White" />
            <DynamicSelectedStyle BackColor="#FF0066" ForeColor="White"/>
            <Items>
    asp:MenuItem NavigateUrl="~/Index.aspx" Text="Home" Value="Home"></asp:MenuItem>
</Items>
            <StaticHoverStyle BackColor="#68655C" ForeColor="White" />
            <StaticMenuItemStyle HorizontalPadding="5px" VerticalPadding="5px"  />
            <StaticSelectedStyle BackColor="#B2223D" ForeColor="White" />
        </asp:Menu>
```

Comment: Qual código .cs você tem até o momento?

Comment: @PauloHDSousa Nada, apaguei tudo.

Comment: O usuário já se encontra autenticado, você quer que ele faça login novamente ao acessar o menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se quiser utilizar a mesma autenticação de entrada do sistema, você poderia forçar um logout utilizando `FormsAuthentication.SignOut();` quando ele clicasse no menu "Home" e redirecionar ele para uma URL de autenticação, assim: `Response.Redirect("~/Login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2fIndex.aspx");`. Isso o obrigaria a autenticar novamente e o redirecionaria para a página de "Home"